# Easeljs : Is there a way to convert SVG to Shape or JSON to Shape

Tags: html, canvas, svg, easeljs

I have a SVG data on the server and send this to the browser. I wanted to convert that SVG data to a Easeljs Shape object to masking operation. I can't find any good reference to do this.

If SVG to Shape is impossible, is there any other way to achieve the same result e.g. JSON to Shape.

Thanks